# Make headers of external Objective-C libraries available in Swift syntax

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, frameworks, swift, cocoapods

In my Swift project, I'd like to use [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) and [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

If I import them using CocoaPod as a static library and if I Cmd+Click on a class that I use, I can only see the header of this class in its Objective-C representation.

However my fellow developers only understand Swift code, but no Objective-C code. Therefore I like to import RestKit and AFNetworking in a way, that Cmd+Clicking shows the Swift representation of the header file, like it is for Apple frameworks.

Is there a possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to the problem. The Swift representation of Objective-C header files is only available, if you import RestKit and AFNetworking as Cocoa Touch Framework and not as Cocoa Touch Static Library.

Unfortunately RestKit and AFNetworking currently only have targets for static libraries.

However you can create a Cocoa Touch Framework for them and copy all Objective-C files into the framework and make them public (be careful with some imports in header files, see e.g. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/2206).

You have to create this Cocoa Touch Framework on your own, you cannot use CocoaPods in the current version. I hope this is possible in the future.